# Copy div text content using javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress, shortcode

There are quite a few posts on this but after spending several hours trying to adapt the solutions that already exist, it's become clear to me that this is a little bit more complicated.

I'm attempting to create 'copy to clipboard' functionality so that our users can copy their serial number with a single click (I managed to achieve this functionality with 2 different solutions) but there's a major catch.

As the serial number is generated dynamically using a shortcode I cannot place it inside a HTML 'text'/'value' field, like so:

```
<input id="serial" value="[shortcode here]">
```

as this breaks the shortcode, so it has to be placed inside it's own div, which I have done like this:

```
<div id="serial">[shortcode here]</div>
```

This outputs the shortcode on the page with the direct parent ID of 'serial', so the JS I'm using should then select the text from the element ID - **#serial**.

Unfortunately it doesn't...

---

I've tried to adapt this method also with no luck:

From the **Roll Your Own** section: https://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-copy-to-clipboard/

*This one was working with with plain text but not with the shortcode or custom div.*

---

Can anyone provide me with a working clipboard solution as shown in the example above that won't break the shortcode?

Comment: I think it is possible to place your code inside HTML input element. You can do it easily by jquery/javascript. After that you can apply your method of copying text.

Comment: Post your JS...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
document.getElementById("copyButton").addEventListener("click", function() {
    copyToClipboardMsg(document.getElementById("copyTarget"), "msg");
});

document.getElementById("copyButton2").addEventListener("click", function() {
    copyToClipboardMsg(document.getElementById("copyTarget2"), "msg");
});

document.getElementById("pasteTarget").addEventListener("mousedown", function() {
    this.value = "";
});


function copyToClipboardMsg(elem, msgElem) {
   var succeed = copyToClipboard(elem);
    var msg;
    if (!succeed) {
        msg = "Copy not supported or blocked.  Press Ctrl+c to copy."
    } else {
        msg = "Text copied to the clipboard."
    }
    if (typeof msgElem === "string") {
        msgElem = document.getElementById(msgElem);
    }
    msgElem.innerHTML = msg;
    setTimeout(function() {
        msgElem.innerHTML = "";
    }, 2000);
}

function copyToClipboard(elem) {
   // create hidden text element, if it doesn't already exist
    var targetId = "_hiddenCopyText_";
    var isInput = elem.tagName === "INPUT" || elem.tagName === "TEXTAREA";
    var origSelectionStart, origSelectionEnd;
    if (isInput) {
        // can just use the original source element for the selection and copy
        target = elem;
        origSelectionStart = elem.selectionStart;
        origSelectionEnd = elem.selectionEnd;
    } else {
        // must use a temporary form element for the selection and copy
        target = document.getElementById(targetId);
        if (!target) {
            var target = document.createElement("textarea");
            target.style.position = "absolute";
            target.style.left = "-9999px";
            target.style.top = "0";
            target.id = targetId;
            document.body.appendChild(target);
        }
        target.textContent = elem.textContent;
    }
    // select the content
    var currentFocus = document.activeElement;
    target.focus();
    target.setSelectionRange(0, target.value.length);
    
    // copy the selection
    var succeed;
    try {
       succeed = document.execCommand("copy");
    } catch(e) {
        succeed = false;
    }
    // restore original focus
    if (currentFocus && typeof currentFocus.focus === "function") {
        currentFocus.focus();
    }
    
    if (isInput) {
        // restore prior selection
        elem.setSelectionRange(origSelectionStart, origSelectionEnd);
    } else {
        // clear temporary content
        target.textContent = "";
    }
    return succeed;
}
```

```html
<input id="copyTarget" value="Some initial text"> <button id="copyButton">Copy</button><br><br>
<span id="copyTarget2">Some Other Text</span> <button id="copyButton2">Copy</button><br><br>
<input id="pasteTarget"> Click in this Field and hit Ctrl+V to see what is on clipboard<br><br>
<span id="msg"></span><br>
```

Would you please try above snippet?

Comment: @puvik7373 Yes! - this worked perfectly with very little adaption, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Second @pruvik7373 answer

I think [shortcode] may contain some code which can translate into anything else so instead of using `textContent` use `innerHTML` it will make sure to copy everything as it is.

```js
document.getElementById("copyButton").addEventListener("click", function() {
    copyToClipboardMsg(document.getElementById("copyTarget"), "msg");
});

document.getElementById("copyButton2").addEventListener("click", function() {
    copyToClipboardMsg(document.getElementById("serial"), "msg");
});

document.getElementById("pasteTarget").addEventListener("mousedown", function() {
    this.value = "";
});


function copyToClipboardMsg(elem, msgElem) {
   var succeed = copyToClipboard(elem);
    var msg;
    if (!succeed) {
        msg = "Copy not supported or blocked.  Press Ctrl+c to copy."
    } else {
        msg = "Text copied to the clipboard."
    }
    if (typeof msgElem === "string") {
        msgElem = document.getElementById(msgElem);
    }
    msgElem.innerHTML = msg;
    setTimeout(function() {
        msgElem.innerHTML = "";
    }, 2000);
}

function copyToClipboard(elem) {
   // create hidden text element, if it doesn't already exist
    var targetId = "_hiddenCopyText_";
    var isInput = elem.tagName === "INPUT" || elem.tagName === "TEXTAREA";
    var origSelectionStart, origSelectionEnd;
    if (isInput) {
        // can just use the original source element for the selection and copy
        target = elem;
        origSelectionStart = elem.selectionStart;
        origSelectionEnd = elem.selectionEnd;
    } else {
        // must use a temporary form element for the selection and copy
        target = document.getElementById(targetId);
        if (!target) {
            var target = document.createElement("textarea");
            target.style.position = "absolute";
            target.style.left = "-9999px";
            target.style.top = "0";
            target.id = targetId;
            document.body.appendChild(target);
        }
        target.textContent = elem.innerHTML;
    }
    // select the content
    var currentFocus = document.activeElement;
    target.focus();
    target.setSelectionRange(0, target.value.length);
    
    // copy the selection
    var succeed;
    try {
       succeed = document.execCommand("copy");
    } catch(e) {
        succeed = false;
    }
    // restore original focus
    if (currentFocus && typeof currentFocus.focus === "function") {
        currentFocus.focus();
    }
    
    if (isInput) {
        // restore prior selection
        elem.setSelectionRange(origSelectionStart, origSelectionEnd);
    } else {
        // clear temporary content
        target.textContent = "";
    }
    return succeed;
}
```

```html
<input id="copyTarget" value="Some initial text"> <button id="copyButton">Copy</button><br><br>
<div id="serial"><div>[pw_map address="New York City"</div> enablescrollwheel="false" key="YOUR API KEY"]</div> <button id="copyButton2">Copy</button><br><br>
<input id="pasteTarget"> Click in this Field and hit Ctrl+V to see what is on clipboard<br><br>
<span id="msg"></span><br>
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code did the trick for me.

**Note:** Below snippet might not work as `window` object is not accessible.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#serial').click(function() {
    window.clipboardData.setData('text', $(this).text());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="serial">[shortcode here]</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do it like:

```
 <div id="serial">[shortcode here]</div>
 <input id="some_other_id" type="text" />
```

And the javascript code:

```
             //first get text from your div and put it inside input field
             //then apply code to copy that text from input field
             $(document).ready(function(){
                 var text = $("#serial").text();
                 $("#some_other_id").val(text);
                   //your code for copying text from input field goes here
             });
```